# Simple.data select top N records

Tags: simple.data

I'm using Simple.Data to select data from a table and am wondering if there is a way to select the top 10 records from the table.

Something like:

```
var result = _database.UserList.All()
            .Select(_database.UserList.Name).Take(10)  -- or .Top(10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something exactly like:

```
var result = _database.UserList.All()
             .Select(_database.UserList.Name).Take(10);
```

More info on Take and Skip in this blog post: http://blog.markrendle.net/simple-data-0-8-0-and-more/

While we're here, it's worth mentioning that if you just want those names as strings, you can do this:

```
var result = _database.UserList.All()
             .Select(_database.UserList.Name)
             .Take(10)
             .ToScalarList<string>();
```

Comment: mmm OK don't know why it wasn't working, but I just added a distinct and where clause and I'm now getting: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'distinct'.

Comment: To fix the incorrect syntax error I just needed to move the distinct before the select, but I don't know why!

Comment: Your link is dead @Mark Rendle, the article is now at http://blog.markrendle.net/simple-data-0-8-0-and-more/